# Why it asks me to input password here to restart db

Tags: postgresql, replication

I just have done

> pg_basebackup -h primary_host -p primary_port -D PGDATA -U replication user

and I jsut wanted to restart the db, so I did

> sudo su - postgres

> sudo service postgres restart

and the ec2 says to me

> Respect the privacy of others, think before you type, ...

and it asks me password for postgres.
But since I have created this ec2 instance, I have never set any password for postgres.
So there is no password for this actually, but it keeps asking me...

I guess there might be something related to pg_basebackup, but I have no idea, because the primary db also has no specific password..

What should I do here, thanks

Comment: I dont think so, it says '[sudo] password for postgres:'

Comment: Services are managed by `root` user, so use `sudo su - ` and then restart

Comment: Then true, you've run the second command from the shell given to you by the first one. This is wrong, don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
sudo su - postgres
```

It invokes a *new* shell, which is owned by postgres user.

Then, *from that shell* you run *another* sudo:

```
sudo service postgres restart
```

And it, unsurprisingly, asks password for the current system user, which is *postgres*, because you ran it from the shell that belongs to postgress. Again, this is not because you set or did not set password for postgres, and this is not about database user postgres, but the OS account, whose shell was invoked with the first command.

Just skip the first command, or exit that shell when you've finished doing things as postgres system account. You should manage services with sudo from your normal admin user, not from postgres user.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But may I ask one more question here? so, inside the su - postgres bash, when I type 'psql --version', then it prints the version. but when I type 'psql -U root' or just 'psql', then it says 'psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory'...

when I type 'sudo pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql/data start', it says 'pg_ctl: could not open PID file: permission denied'

anyway I need to connect to the pgsql prompt...

Comment: Run `psql -U postgres` from that postgres-user shell.

Comment: Thanks it was the problem of the ownership of the directory